# Is it okay to use my US visa after a name change?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, passport-renewals

I had my US visa about 7 month age, and I had to renew my passport for certain circumstances, so there was a mismatch in the name between both the visa and the new passport, you see they had to put my grand grandfather's name which was not on the old passport nor the visa, the name on old passport and visa is: Abdelrahman Samy Ali Mohammed
and the new passport is: Abdelrahman Samy Ali Ibrahim Mohammed.
My grand grandfather's name is Ibrahim, so the question is that gonna cause me any troubles concerning my entry to the US? is there any document should I consider taking it while i'm traveling? 
Thanks,,

Comment: Who decided to change you name, why, and what paperwork did you have to support the change?

Comment: @Gagravarr Is the "who" and "why" part relevant?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I can see the process being very different if the OP decided to change their own name, or if their home government did it, or their home government caught up on a "less than truthful" passport which was cancelled + they had to confess plus get one in their proper name

Comment: @Gagravarr You honestly think that the interpretation "I had a visa in a passport that I'd obtained fraudulently in a false name and now I've had to get a passport in my real name" is even remotely likely? Seriously? People change their name legitimately for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: They do, but given some of the other questions we've had about people needing to change details on their passports (dates of births, names etc), it's worth checking as the answer is completely different!

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to answer the question.

1. The guidance provided in the other answers has been changed to "If your name has legally changed through marriage ... the Department of State *recommends* that you apply for a new U.S. visa"

2. My wife recently travelled to US with a visa she was issued before we got married in 2015 (valid for 10 years). Her visa is stamped on her old passport and the surname on the visa is different from the surname on her current passport. She just had to through an extra fingerprint check and everything went fine. She did not have any issues.

Answer (score 13):

Various U.S. embassy web sites note that, when your name has changed, you can travel with the old visa and documents which show evidence of the name change. You also need official English translations of the name change documents.

For instance:

> [My last name has changed due to marriage. I have a visa with my maiden name in my old passport. Should I apply for a new visa?](http://turkey.usembassy.gov/niv-faqs-general-questions.html#11)
>
> No. You may travel to U.S by carrying your old and new passport along with your marriage certificate.

> [If I already have a valid visa and I change my name (through marriage, or for other reasons), can I use my old visa?](http://bangkok.usembassy.gov/non-immigrant_visas/frequently-asked-questions.html#3)
>
> Yes. As long as your passport is still valid for at least six months beyond the date you plan on traveling, you may use your existing visa. However, you should carry proof of your legal name change (i.e., the Thai name change certificate with a certified English translation) with you when you travel to the U.S. If you wish to reduce the likelihood of encountering a delay at the port of entry, you are welcome to apply for a new visa by following our normal application procedures.

You are also [allowed to apply for a new visa](http://manila.usembassy.gov/wwwhni25.html#03), if you wish. You should also apply for a new visa if the reason your name changed was to correct an error in the previous name.

> Visa holders of valid visas on passports reflecting their incorrect, old, assumed name, such as the following, may reapply for a nonimmigrant visa :
>
> - incorrect spelling of the name
> - without the second name (ex: “Jose Reyes dela Cruz” instead of “Jose Pedro Reyes dela Cruz”)
> - without a suffix (Jr., Sr., III, etc.)
> - Ma. instead of Maria
>
> To reapply, please comply with the Nonimmigrant Visa Application Procedures.

Answer (score 4):

The answer seems to depend on the source country.

With some countries, you are allowed to enter using the old visa and documents in English, proving the change in name. For example,

> [I have a visa but it has my maiden/married name. Now I’m married/divorced, and my name has changed. Do I need a new visa?](https://br.usembassy.gov/visas/frequently-asked-questions-non-immigrant-visas/)
>
> You don’t need a new visa. You can travel with your new passport with your married or maiden name, and your old passport and visa, with your maiden or married name. A copy of your marriage or divorce certificate will assist in clarifying any questions. Make sure that the visa has not been damaged before you travel.

With some other countries, you may have to apply for a new visa. For example,

> [Do I need to apply for a new visa if my personally identifiable information has changed?](https://co.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/niv-faq/)
>
> Only if personal information on your passport, such as: Name, last name, date of birth or gender, have changed, you will have to apply for a new visa noting the updated information. All printed information on your visa must match that on your passport.