# Is the US visa cancelled if the passport is cancelled?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I am from India.

I had to cancel my old passport to get a new one because I had a change in my surname.
The old one has a [B-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_visa#Acceptable_uses_of_a_B-1_visa)/[B-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_visa#Acceptable_uses_of_a_B-1_visa) US visa with an expiry in the year 2027.

I have plans to visit the US soon on business, and I am reapplying for a visa.

There is a question in the visa application form:

> Has your U.S. Visa ever been cancelled or revoked?

What should I choose? **Yes** or **No**?

Comment: If a passport is replaced, the previous passport is invalid (and is probably returned to you) but any visas in it are not cancelled. The passport issuer does not have authority to cancel visas for other countries.

Comment: Why not just use your existing visa?  (See [Is it okay to use my US visa after a name change?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65251/19400))

Comment: @WeatherVane: you should be carefu on what you writel. On many countries (but not US, so not in this case), if you cancel a passport, the visa is automatically considered cancelled, not by the passport issuing country, but the visa issuing country. (for US: ESTA and VWP is attached to a "valid" passport, so automatically cancelled if you change passport.)

Comment: @WeatherVane in addition to what bGiacomo Catenazzi says, if the cancelled passport is cut, and that cut also damages the visa inside the passport, many countries that would otherwise consider the visa valid will consider that the damage to the visa renders it invalid.  So it depends in part on what the issuing country does to the passport when cancelling it.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I read in a few places where I was informed that its the airlines that cause troubles due to name mismatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should choose **No**. Cancelling your passport doesn’t mean your visa is cancelled or revoked. See [Will a valid, non-expired US Visa work on a cancelled passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180241/will-a-valid-non-expired-us-visa-work-on-a-cancelled-passport)

Examples of common grounds for visa revocation or cancellation include:

- Visa was fraudulently-issued or was used in a fraudulent manner
- Suspected immigrant intent
- Suspected unauthorized employment
- Suspected status violation
- No longer qualify for the visa (e.g., due to criminal activity)
- Prudential revocation by issuing U.S. Embassy or U.S. Consulate following an arrest in the United States for DUI or other crimes
- Cancellation of nonimmigrant visa following adjustment of status

Comment: Should choose no or should rethink the plan to get a new visa: [Is it okay to use my US visa after a name change?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65251/19400)